# MySQL Left Outer Join to each on right only once

Tags: mysql, join

I'm doing a left outer join but I only want it to pull a match from the right table once.

For example, I want to query `requirements` table, left outer joining the `activity` table but with matching only the first result without duplicates on the right.

Example:

Requirements Table

```
requirement_number   requirement_type 

1                    class   
2                    class  
3                    project  
4                    project  
5                    cert  
6                    interview
```

Activity Table

```
activity_number     activity_type     activity_name

1                   class             class1  
2                   class             class2  
3                   class             class3  
4                   project           project1  
5                   project           project2  
6                   project           project3  
7                   cert              cert1  
8                   cert              cert2  
9                   cert              cert3
```

Result:

```
requirement_number   requirement_type   activity_type   activity_name
1                    class              class           class1
2                    class              class           class2
3                    project            project         project1
4                    project            project         project2
5                    cert               cert            cert1
6                    interview          interview       NULL
```

Comment: What's the joining column between ACTIVITY and REQUIREMENT?

Comment: requirement_type = activity_type

Comment: You don't have an 'activity_type'="Interview" in the activity table. Does this mean that column of output actually represents the requirement_type?

Comment: For this example, the goal is to show what "requirements" are met and what are not met.  So, the results will show that all of the requirements are not met.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
GROUP BY requirement_number
```

Comment: This will not give the required result, since line 1 and 2 will have the same result for activity_name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
r.requirement_number,
r.requirement_type,
a.activity_type,
min(a.activity_name)
from  requirements r 
left join activity a
  on r.requirement_type  =  a.activity_type
group by r.requirement_number,
r.requirement_type,
a.activity_type
```

This is on the assumption you want the "lowest" activity_name. If you want the first instance, you will have to include activity_number in the result set, and use the MIN function on that instead.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8debaf/3) to demonstrate...

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is much closer and my first exposure to SQLFiddle, which is very nice!  Looking at the SQL Fiddle results, I would like Result line 2 and 4 to be different.  They should show Class2 and Project2 respectively.

Comment: The best way to do that would be to add a "requirement_id" foreign key to the activity table, and to join on that instead. Is that possible?